How do Borg's "prune" work with deduplication?
Here's how I currently (mis)understand how it works : everytime I run
borg create /path/to/my/repo::[archive name] /home/myData

Borg creates a new archive. Thanks to the deduplication mechanism, this archive :

contains the data chunks that were not seen before (basically : new files and data added to existing files)
"links" (referring to previous archives) to the data chunks that are already known + stored by Borg

Meaning that, if I create successive archives with the borg create [...] command above :

the archive_1 has a full copy of /home/myData as of the day I ran that command for the first time
thanks to the deduplication mechanism, the archive_2 only has the chunks of data I added to /home/myData since the creation of archive_1
...
the archive_n only has the the chunks of data I added to /home/myData since the creation of archive_(n-1)

How is it even possible to prune a repository without losing data, since every archive has a unique set of chunks ? I'm obviously missing something, but what ?
Is there a method / best practice to make a "full backup" every once in a while ? I've read (but lost the link :-( that Borg doesn't support full / incremental backups. Does that mean that, should I want to perform a new full backup of /home/myData, I'll have to :

borg init [options] /path/to/new/repo
borg create /path/to/new/repo::[archive name] /home/myData


Borg has two "removal" actions - prune and compact
See the diagram from the object graph documentation here: https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/internals/data-structures.html#the-object-graph

The manifest contains keys of Archives, Archives refer to Files, and Files refer to Chunks.
Prune removes Archives from the graph which do not match the specified retention policies. But it does not change any files/chunks that are referenced. A file can be referenced by multiple archives, which is how differential snapshots are performed (files/chunks that do not change are simply referenced).
Borg compact operates at the lower key/value store layer to actually reclaim the deleted space from deleted data in the upper archive layer. This actually deletes the data, versus dereferencing it.
